# altering values in a pandas df based on column value length

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to change some incorrect values in a df. If the values in the 'subject' column are 3 characters long, they should have a '0' added to them to make them correct. The below code doesn't work, but kind of shows what I'm trying to do. Any help would be appreciated.

```
df.loc[df['subject'].len() == 3, 'subject'] = '0' + the current value
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use [.str.zfill()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.zfill.html) method:

```
df.subject = df.subject.str.zfill(4)
```

alternatively, you can do this:

```
df.loc[df['subject'].str.len() == 3, 'subject'] = '0' + df['subject']
```

but i would choose the first option